# I don't know why the loop doesn't stop! Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

This is my first doubt here, i'm really noob on this and my english isn't the best, so first of all sorry if there's a dummie mistake. 
The thing is that I want to do a for loop to save every user input from console and add it to a list named "Order". This action have to be done if the user type correctly the order and it have to be checked to know if that exists on the menu. If it doesn't we have to let the user know the situation and ask him/her if he/she wants something we have on the menu. Also after every input saved on the listed we want to ask the user if he/she wants to order something more, so if is YES the loop have to be initialized and if is NO we have to get out the loop. 
The problem with my code is that no matter what I type in the console, the loop is done from start to finish every cicle. 
Where is the error?
Thanks!!!

````
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fase2_final {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String[] menu = { "chicken", "steak", "hamburger", "spaghettis", "pizza" };
        int[] price = { 10, 15, 20, 5, 12 };
        boolean order = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {

            System.out.println("We have " + menu[i] + " for " + price[i] + "€");

        }

        int yes = 1;
        int no = 0;

        Scanner yesOrNo = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What do you want to eat?");

        List<String> Order = new ArrayList<String>();

        do {

            Scanner inputOrder = new Scanner(System.in);

            String userOrder = inputOrder.next().toLowerCase();

            for (int j = 0; j < menu.length; j++) {

                if (userOrder.equals(menu[j])) {

                    Order.add(userOrder);

                    System.out.println("You ordered" + Order + "\nSomething more?" + "\nSay YES with 1 and NO with 0");

                } else if (userOrder.equals(menu[j]) == false) {

                    System.out.println("We don't have this on menu!"
                            + "\nDo you want to order another thing that we do have in menu?" + "\nSay YES with 1 and NO with 0");

                } else if (yesOrNo.nextInt() == no) {

                    System.out.println("Order finished!");

                }

            }
        } while (yesOrNo.nextInt() == yes);
    }
}```
````

Comment: Hint: each `nextInt()` call returns separate value which is why we don't place it in conditions directly but rather store value in variable and use that variable in conditions.

Comment: Hint2: don't use many Scanners to read from same resource. It makes things complicated since Scanners read entire available data, so even if user will provide data like `1 2 3[enterKey]` `nextInt()` will return `1` but `2 3` will also be read by that scanner preventing other scanner from reading them.

Comment: ok, then i will change both scanners and do only one named `sc` to check the inputs, but what can i use to substitute the `nextInt()`? I need to know if the user are putting yes or no to know what the programm have to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to re-declare the Scanner object every iteration, or to have more than one Scanner object that will read from the same source. Also, there is no need to print out "I didn't find it!" over every comparison.

Consider the following block of code:

```
.
.
.
// there is no need to re-declare the Scanner object every iteration, or two scanners
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

do {
    String userOrder = keyboard.next().toLowerCase();

    // we haven't found the item
    boolean found = false;

    // integer option (yes or no)
    int option;

    // do the search
    for (int j = 0; j < menu.length; j++) {
        // do this if found
        if (userOrder.equals(menu[j])) {
            // set flag to indicate we found the item
            found = true;

            // add the order
            Order.add(userOrder);

            // print out, then read the user's option
            System.out.println("You ordered" + userOrder + "\nSomething more?" + "\nSay YES with 1 and NO with 0");
            option = keyboard.nextInt();

            // consume the NL leftover from the nextInt() call
            keyboard.nextLine();

            // break out of the for loop since you already found what you're looking for
            break;
        }
    }

    // check if you didn't find the item
    if (!found) {
        // print out
        System.out.println("We don't have this on menu!"
                            + "\nDo you want to order another thing that we do have in menu?" + "\nSay YES with 1 and NO with 0");

        // read if user wants to continue
        option = keyboard.nextInt();

        // consume the NL leftover from the nextInt() call
        keyboard.nextLine();        
    }
} while (option == yes);

System.out.println("Order finished!");
.
.
.
// close the scanner when you're done
keyboard.close();
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

the nextInt() method returns the current input one time, if you call it twice it needs a second input. It could should look like this:

```java
do {

    Scanner inputOrder = new Scanner(System.in);

    String userOrder = inputOrder.next().toLowerCase();
    int answer = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < menu.length; j++) {

        if (userOrder.equals(menu[j])) {

            Order.add(userOrder);

            System.out.println("You ordered" + Order + "\nSomething more?" + "\nSay YES with 1 and NO with 0");

        } else if (userOrder.equals(menu[j]) == false) {

            System.out.println("We don't have this on menu!"
            + "\nDo you want to order another thing that we do have in menu?" + "\nSay YES with 1 and NO with 0");

        } else if ((answer = yesOrNo.nextInt()) == no) {

            System.out.println("Order finished!");

        }

    }
} while (yesOrNo.nextInt() == answer);
```

I hope I answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have refactored your code . try to see in comparing tool .

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fase2_final {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String[] menu = { "chicken", "steak", "hamburger", "spaghettis", "pizza" };
        int[] price = { 10, 15, 20, 5, 12 };
        boolean order = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {

            System.out.println("We have " + menu[i] + " for " + price[i] + "€");

        }
        int decision = 0;
        int yes = 1;
        int no = 0;

        Scanner yesOrNo = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What do you want to eat?");

        List<String> Order = new ArrayList<String>();

        do {

            Scanner inputOrder = new Scanner(System.in);

            String userOrder = inputOrder.next().toLowerCase();

            for (int j = 0; j < menu.length; j++) {

                if (userOrder.equals(menu[j])) {

                    Order.add(userOrder);

                    System.out.println("You ordered" + Order + "\nSomething more?" + "\nSay YES with 1 and NO with 0");

                } else if (userOrder.equals(menu[j]) == false) {

                    System.out.println("We don't have this on menu!"
                            + "\nDo you want to order another thing that we do have in menu?" + "\nSay YES with 1 and NO with 0");

                } 

            }

            decision = yesOrNo.nextInt();
             if (decision == no) {

                System.out.println("Order finished!");

            }
        } while (decision == yes);
    }
}
```

*Always close the scanner when you are done .*